# Fetching unique records in a comma separated values from a column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have got the following records in a table.

```
Country      |  Values
-------------+-----------------------------
 Fruits      | Apple, orange,Pineapple
 Animals     | Lion, Jaguar
 Foods       | Muffins, Sandwitch
 Cold Fruit  | Water melon, Pineapple
```

Im trying to fetch all records from the values column as an array without any duplicate elements. How can i be able to do so using sqlite in android?

As of now, Im fetching all records from values column to an array. Then Im parsing comma separated values and Im adding it to a new array while filtering duplicate elements.

Comment: Can we see some code? Can't you split on ",", trim and add to a `Set` each "Values"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly normalize your database:

```
CountryID Country
--------- ----------
 1        Fruits
 2        Animals
 3        Foods
 4        Cold Fruit

Value       CountryID
----------- ---------
Apple        1
orange       1
Pineapple    1
Lion         2
Jaguar       2
Muffins      3
Sandwitch    3
Water melon  4
Pineapple    4
```

Then the query becomes trivial:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM ValuesTable;
```